# Corrupted H.264 file: NAL unit header mystery

Tags: networking, streaming, h.264

I'm currently facing a challenge for university with a corrupted H.264 file and could use some guidance.

As part of an exercise, I've been examining the H.264 stream, which is composed of NAL units. I've successfully identified the start of NAL units using the sequences `0x00 00 00 01` or `0x00 00 01`, followed by a header consisting of `nal_ref_idc`, `nal_unit_type`.

However, my search for corrupt NAL units has left me puzzled. The only headers I've found are `67`, `68`, `01`, `41`, and none of them seem to indicate a corrupt NAL unit. I've searched the internet for examples of corrupt NAL units without success.

Am I misunderstanding how NAL units work, or is there a specific header pattern for corrupt units?

To provide some context, here's the beginning of the H.264 stream:

```
00 00 00 01 67 64 00 32 AC D9 80 78 02 27 E5 C0 5A 80 80 80 A0 00 00 7D 20 00 1D 4C 01 E3 06 33 40 00 00 00 01 68 E9 78 F2 C8 B0 00 00 01 06 05 FF FF AB DC 45 E9 BD E6 D9 48 B7 96 2C D8 20 D9 23 EE EF 78 32 36 34 20 2D 20 63 6F 72 65 20 31 36 33 20 72 33 30 36 30 20 35 64 62 36 61 61 36
```

Any insights or examples of corrupt NAL units would be greatly appreciated, as it would help me with understanding it.